# flutter - while I change text on textFormField cursor moves to start

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I made a notetaking app but I found a bug that when ever I click on field it moves cursor to start of field I want it to be in the end of already written text there.
Code:

```
          Padding (
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, bottom: 15.0),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: titleContr,
              style: textStyle,
              validator: (String value) {
                if (value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a title';
                }
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Title',
                labelStyle: textStyle,
                hintText: 'Add a title for the Task',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                )
              ),
            )
          ),
```

Comment: what version of flutter are you using ?

Comment: @diegoveloper 1 i guess.

Comment: @diegoveloper didn't work, already up to date.

Comment: so the cursor moves to start of field if you click on it or you change text in it?

Comment: @pskink when I click on it.

Comment: no, if you click the sursor goes to the point where you click inside text field

Comment: that what not happening @pskink

Answer (score 1):

This doc may help:

[material 3 text-fields](https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/overview)

[material text field](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html), code example

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [TextField].

class ObscuredTextFieldSample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ObscuredTextFieldSample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox(
      width: 250,
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Password',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TextFieldExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldExampleApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Obscured Textfield')),
        body: const Center(
          child: ObscuredTextFieldSample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const TextFieldExampleApp());
```